WPF Chart is not updating
my program consists of a chart from LiveCharts library, which is bound to a sqlite query, this sqlite query will change depending on the selected item of a combobox, i want this change in the sqlite query to also mean a change in the chart. here is my code:
cs:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using LiveCharts;
using LiveCharts.Wpf;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using INotify;


namespace example
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Lógica de interacción para Charts.xaml
   /// </summary>
  public partial class Charts : Window
  {

      string dow = "";
      public Charts()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
       
        
        
          comboBox.SelectedIndex = 1;
        
       }

    

      public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
      public string[] Labels { get; set; }
      public Func<int, string> Formatter { get; set; }

      

    

      private void ComboBox_DropDownClosed_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)comboBox.SelectedItem;
        dow = cbi.Content.ToString();
        label.Content = dow;
        List<int> amount = new List<int>();
        List<string> product = new List<string>();

        DatabaseHelper dbh = new DatabaseHelper();
        SQLiteConnection connection;
        connection = dbh.Createconnection();
        String loadchart = "SELECT product, count(product) AS Amount FROM table_productsold WHERE DATE like '" + dow + "%' GROUP BY product; ";

        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(loadchart, connection);
        SQLiteDataReader reader;
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();


        while (reader.Read())
        {
            amount.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["Amount"]));
            product.Add(reader["product"].ToString());
        }

        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new ColumnSeries
            {
                Title = "2015",
                Values = new ChartValues<int>(amount)
            }
        };

        //adding series will update and animate the chart automatically


        Labels = product.ToArray();
        Formatter = value => value.ToString("N");

        DataContext = this;
        
        connection.Close();
        dow = "";
    }
}

}
xaml:
<Window x:Class="example.Charts"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
         
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Charts" Height="450" Width="899.067">
<Grid x:Name="grid">
    <lvc:CartesianChart x:Name="chartp" Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" LegendLocation="Left" Width="500" Height="400" Panel.ZIndex="-1" Margin="81,10,311.8,10" >
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis Title="Salesman" Labels="{Binding Labels}"></lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:Axis Title="Sold Apps" LabelFormatter="{Binding Formatter}"></lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
    <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="713,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged" DropDownClosed="ComboBox_DropDownClosed_1">
        
        
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Lun"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Mar"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Mie"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Jue"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Vie"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Sab"/>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Dom"/>
        
    </ComboBox>
    <Label x:Name="label" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="685,220,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>

My sqlite helper:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Windows;

namespace example
{
  class DatabaseHelper
  {
      public SQLiteConnection Createconnection()
      {
          SQLiteConnection connection;
          connection = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source=C:\Users\Alan\source\repos\example\example\example.db;New=True;Compress=True;" );

          try
          {
              connection.Open();
              MessageBox.Show("Could connect ");

          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
            MessageBox.Show("Could not connect " + ex.Message);
          }
          return connection;
      }

    
      public void createtablelogs(SQLiteConnection conn)
      {
          SQLiteCommand command;
          string ctl = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_productsold(product TEXT NOT NULL, price int, DATE TEXT NOT NULL);";
          command = conn.CreateCommand();
          command.CommandText = ctl;
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }

    

  
    
      public void insertProductsold(SQLiteConnection conn, string products, int prices)
      {
        SQLiteCommand command;
        string insert = "INSERT INTO table_productsold VALUES('"+products+"',"+prices+",  case cast(strftime('%w', 'now', 'localtime')as integer)" +
            "when 0 then 'Dom' ||' '|| strftime('%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M', 'now', 'localtime') " +
            "when 1 then 'Lun' ||' '|| strftime('%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M', 'now', 'localtime')" +
            "when 2 then 'Mar' ||' '|| strftime('%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M', 'now', 'localtime')" +
            "when 3 then 'Mie' ||' '|| strftime('%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M', 'now', 'localtime')" +
            "when 4 then 'Jue' ||' '|| strftime('%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M', 'now', 'localtime')" +
            "when 5 then 'Vie' ||' '|| strftime('%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M', 'now', 'localtime')" +
            "when 6 then 'Sab' ||' '|| strftime('%Y/%m/%d, %H:%M', 'now', 'localtime')" +
            "end);";
        command = conn.CreateCommand();

        command.CommandText = insert;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

      }

    
  }
}

So the sqlite query will change depending on the selected item of the combobox, thus changing the chart as well.
When i run this code, it works as intended but only once, when i select another item in the combobox it all remains the same.
i would really appreciate your help

Seems like you are recreating SerialCollection Object instead of updating it. So either you will have to call INotifyPropertyChange on it or clear it and refill it with the new data set
